# Not a coincidence

Tags: probability

Your company has successfully made 140 sales since they started promoting the new product. The other owner, who is very superstitious, notices that today is the 140th day of the year, and believes that it must be a sign that the company made the 140th sale on the 140th day. You, however, are much more rational. You would like to think that there was some mechanism that made the days and the sales line up, but you know that the sales were made irregularly and with no planning by the company or clients. You look at the records and conclude that it must be a coincidence.

However, both you and your partner are wrong. There was no cosmic force involved, but it was also not a coincidence. It had to happen. What caused the numbers to line up?

Maybe a hint:

> The number 140 doesn't matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plot the "sales so far this year" line against the "days so far this year" line (which will be a straight line with a slope of 1), the lines will

> cross

or

> the sales will always be below the days and never cross it

In the first case,

> When the lines cross, they have the same x values and the same y values. So the sales so far this year will equal the days so far this year, as observed.

Note that

> If they sell less than 365 products all year, it's possible the lines will not cross. It's also possible to cross many more times than once.

Comment: I believe this works if the number of sales and days are continuous (the standard [rubber band problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubber+band+problem+intermediate+value+theorem&oq=rubber+band+problem+intermediate+value+theorem&aqs=chrome..69i57.9389j0j7&client=ms-android-fi&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#)), but not if discrete, unless mentioned that each day maximum of two sales is possible.

Comment: I see your point. If on Day 10 there have been 5 sales so far, but then there are 10 sales on Day 11, the crossing is not an integer. So there are two cases in which the premise of the question is not correct. The answer remains an explanation of the times the premise is correct.

Comment: Yes, agree with you on that, Kate, the question needs to have more restrictions. Sorry I wasn't clear that that was my point in my previous comment.

Comment: That's if you only look at the sales at the end of the day. If you are watching the sales as they come in, by @KateGregory's example on day 11 you would see the 11th sale come in. I can try to include a description of that in the question if you think it would make sense